# How to search a particular string in a file using pattern matcher in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

**I have the following exception stack trace**

```
java.net.SocketException: ***Connection reset***
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:197)
    at jcifs.netbios.SessionServicePacket.readPacketType(SessionServicePacket.java:68)
    at jcifs.netbios.NbtSocket.connect(NbtSocket.java:107)
    at jcifs.netbios.NbtSocket.<init>(NbtSocket.java:68)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.ensureOpen(SmbTransport.java:275)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:602)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:847)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:790)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:760)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1149)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1232)
    at com.ssc.faw.util.SmbFileOperator.copyFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.newnav2faw.FundList.checkFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.newnav2faw.FundList.buildList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.newnav2faw.Process.buildFundList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.job.NavToFaw.runNav2Faw(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.job.NavToFaw.runNav2Faw(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.job.NavToFaw.runJob(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssc.faw.job.NavToFaw.main(Unknown Source)
[WARN ] 2015-05-05 21:02:26,383 Caught an Exception for file \\ac_asd_2.my_web.com\global\nvice\alert\ filename ***abcd123.xls*** continuing to process other funds 0 : null
jcifs.smb.SmbException: An error occured sending the request.
```

Now the question is, based on the occurence of the word `Connection reset` I need to find the immediate next .xls filename `abcd123.xls` (could be of any name)
Can we do this via REGEX??

Comment: Yes you can do this through regex

Comment: Do you know how to form the script for it??

Comment: Your question did not ask for it :)...do post you attempts as well.....

Comment: LOL
my pattern matching skills are of kindergarden level :P
need sm serious help with this

Comment: Thats the max i know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connection reset.*?\\b([^ .]+\\.xls)\\b
```

You can use this regex.Grab the `group 1` or `capture 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/3

Comment: well thnx this does the job